# Web Api Batch Calls in Asp .net Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have found an article related to reduce web api calls by doing batch web api calls.

Article Link: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web+API+Request+Batching

As per the articke, we could make multiple http web api request in single batch and could receive combined response once all controller action method execution completes and returns response.

But, I want to know, Is it possible to receive response from individual controller action method rather than waiting for each controller action method execution to complete in batch call?

Comment: Do you mean to make one request, but to get multiple async responses?

Comment: yes, I should start receiving response from individual controller action method once its execution completes.